# Returning an INT value of data in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the result below of 2 arrays starting with `[0]` what I am wanting to do is return a result of "2" - As I have 2 "strings".  How would I do this?

**Result:**

```
Array(1) {
    [0]=> string(32) "b5cfec3e70d0d57ea848d5d8b9f14d61"
}
Array(1) {
    [0]=> string(32) "eda80a3d5b344bc40f3bc04f65b7a357"
}
```

**PHP:**

```
    foreach($cart_contents as $key => $row) {

        if(in_array($key, $skip))

            continue;

             $cartData = $row['rowid'];

             $cartDataArray = explode(" ", $cartData);

             $result = $cartDataArray;

             var_dump($result);
    }
```

Comment: give me your correct array format

Comment: Could you explain better?

Comment: `string(32) "b5cfec3e70d0d57ea848d5d8b9f14d61" string(32) "eda80a3d5b344bc40f3bc04f65b7a357"`

Comment: What is the content of `$cartData`? Did you know that `explode` returns an array?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos The result is `string(32) "b5cfec3e70d0d57ea848d5d8b9f14d61" string(32) "eda80a3d5b344bc40f3bc04f65b7a357"` yes I am aware I some how need a way to return a value  of how many strings there are - Thats why I was thinking by using an array

Comment: just a side note: `$result = explode(" ", $row['rowid']);`

Comment: So do you want to COUNT how many string there are in `$result`? Use the function [`count`](http://us3.php.net/count).

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos I have tried that and it gives me `int(1) int(1)`
`

Comment: @Jess McKenzie just echo your $cartData = $row['rowid']; and show me

Comment: @JessMcKenzie yeah thats the result. that means theres 1string + 1string = 2 strings. Its int because COUNT returns the total number of values inside an array.

Comment: @NathanSrivi http://d.pr/i/8GLx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got this right, I think this is what you want:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($cart_contents as $key => $row) {

        if(in_array($key, $skip))
            continue;

        $cartData = $row['rowid'];
        $result = count(explode(" ", $cartData));
        $count += $result;
}
var_dump($count);
```

Comment: I get Unsupported operand types